# Cloudformation - Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method" returns {"message": "Internal server error"}

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I get {"message": "Internal server error"} return from AWS API gateway when I write a Cloudformation template. Everything works well if I configure them on AWS console.

```
curl https://abcdefgh.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/demo/getitems
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

I check all parts in the CF template and I think the problem is in "AWS::ApiGateway::Method". All configuration/parameters are the same between CF template and AWS console ( I checked them on console).  When I delete the method created by CF, re-create and re-deploy it manually, it works.

I believe that "AWS::Lambda::Permission" works because I see it in Resource-based policy.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

The CF template:

```
  apigwGETMethod:
    DependsOn:
      - apiResourceGET
      - lambdaFunction3
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: "GET"
      ResourceId: !Ref apiResourceGET
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "GET"
        Type: "AWS"
        Credentials: !GetAtt ServerlessIAMRole.Arn
        Uri: !Sub
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction3.Arn
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseTemplates:
              "application/json": ""
            StatusCode: 200
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            "application/json": "Empty"
          StatusCode: 200

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn:
      - apiGatewayGETMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: !Ref apiGatewayStageName
      
  lambdaFunction3:
    DependsOn:
      - ServerlessIAMRole
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref lambdaFunction3Name
      Handler: lambda_function3.lambda_handler
      Description: "get all items from DynamoDB table"
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: .
      Role: !GetAtt ServerlessIAMRole.Arn

  lambda3ApiGatewayInvoke:
    DependsOn:
      - lambdaFunction3
      - apiGatewayGETMethod
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt lambdaFunction3.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*"
```

Comment: Try runing `cfn-lint` on your template?

Comment: Are you trying to setup AWS integration or AWS_PROXY integration with lambda?

Comment: Never use ```cfn-lint``` before, I will give it a try.

I'm trying to setup AWS integration with lambda. You can see ```Integration: Type: AWS``` in the template

Comment: I tried cfn-lint, it showed me all syntax errors (such as IntegrationResponses/0/StatusCode should be of type String) and I fixed all of them but the API gw always returns ```"Internal server error"```.